# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.reflection.fieldinfo' to 'devexpress.dataaccess.excel.fieldinfo'

Tags: c#, devexpress

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL87U.png)

> thanks in advance to everyone.... i'm using devexpress xtragridcontrol
>   to display data according to the rows hight. but got problem that,
>   cannot implicitly convert type system.reflection.fieldinfo to
>   devexpress.dataaccess.excel.fieldinfo, any suggestion...
>
> here is my code

```
private void UpdateGridSize()
{
    GridViewInfo viewInfo = (GridViewInfo)gridView2.GetViewInfo();
    DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.FieldInfo fi = typeof(GridView).GetField("scrollInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    ScrollInfo scrollInfo = (ScrollInfo)fi.GetValue(gridView2);
    int width = viewInfo.ViewRects.IndicatorWidth;
    foreach (GridColumn column in gridView1.VisibleColumns)
    {
        if (viewInfo.GetColumnLeftCoord(column) < viewInfo.ViewRects.ColumnPanelWidth)
            gridView1.LeftCoord = width;
        width += viewInfo.ColumnsInfo[column].Bounds.Width;
    }
    if (scrollInfo.VScrollVisible) width += scrollInfo.VScrollSize;
    int height = viewInfo.CalcRealViewHeight(new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width, ClientSize.Height), true);
    if (scrollInfo.HScrollVisible) height += scrollInfo.HScrollSize;
    width = Math.Max(GridMinWidth, width);
    width = Math.Min(ClientSize.Width - gridControl1.Location.X, width);
    height = Math.Max(GridMinHeight, height);
    height = Math.Min(ClientSize.Height - gridControl1.Location.Y, height);
    gridControl1.Size = new Size(width, height);
    gridView1.LayoutChanged();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.FieldInfo with a GridView? Where did you get this code from? It looks like you may have copied some code from the DevExpress Support Center but incorrectly used the Excel.FieldInfo versus a System.Reflection.FieldInfo. My guess is that the code you copied didn't fully qualify the FieldInfo namespace and instead had a using System.Reflection directive which you did not include. You then incorrectly fully qualified it with DevExpress.Data.Excel rather than System.Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The reflection and DevExpress `FieldInfo` types are not related and therefore not assignment compatible. Create a new object and assign the values

```
var fieldInfo = typeof(GridView).GetField("scrollInfo",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); // Reflection

var fi = new DevExpress.DataAccess.Excel.FieldInfo {
    Name = fieldInfo.Name, Type = fieldInfo.MemberType
};
```

---

Or did you mean to do something like this:

```
viewInfo.GetField(...)
```

instead of

```
typeof(GridView).GetField(
```

---

According to DevExpress [the class `GridViewInfo` is not documented and subject to changes](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q406602/where-is-the-gridviewinfo-documentation)

> This class is not documented, because it describes the internal visual grid presentation, which can be dynamically changed depending on development requirements. We tend to prevent our customers from using this class.

Comment: thank you sir the error solved but the grid control not scrolling according to rows in it

Comment: Create a ticket on the DevExpress support site for questions related to their products.